# Prevent elements from wrapping with boostrap pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a search box I want to align to the right side of the page. To the right I want the "GO" button to search.  I'm using pull-right which works fine on large screens however when it scales down, the button drops below the input field. What's the best way to fix this?

```
     <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="clearfix pull-right">
            <form method="get" action="" name="searchForm">
                <div class="form-group form-inline">Keyword Search: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" value=""> 
                    <input type="button" onclick="document.searchForm.submit()" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Large Screen

[image: Large Screen correct]

Small Screen (wraps)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructured your markup and added some custom CSS to replicate the form you have.

Divide each element to various form groups and assign `col-xs-*` classes to each of them.

```css
label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: normal !important; /* Avoid important, added here for the sake of SO snippet */
}
.form-group {
  padding: 0 5px !important;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-inline pull-right">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label>Keyword Search:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" value="" name="search" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Go" onclick="document.searchForm.submit()">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword Search should be a label and you could define a size for the controls.. Check this example :
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal